# Selenium IDE Formatters from command line

Tags: python, selenium, command-line, selenium-ide

Is it possible to convert a selenium IDE test case (selense) to other programming languages by command line ?

for example, to python code.

emphasis on command line option and not using the Selenium IDE.

thanks

Comment: It looks like the IDE's formatters are [JS plugins](https://code.google.com/p/selenium/source/browse/ide/plugins/python-format/src/content/formats/python2-wd.js). There might be a way to run those from the command-line, but I'm not aware of one.

Answer (score 0):

Yes sure! you can convert it.

1)Open your IDE

2)Click File

[image]

3)Click Export Test Case As

[image]

4)Select what language you want to convert!